# How to get a the actual keyname from hardware key-number/scancode in pure python OR: How to bind the key left of the [1] to a shortcut in Qt

Tags: python, qt, keyboard, pyqt, cross-platform

My final goal is to bind the key left of the [1] key to a shortcut in pyqt, no matter what keyboard layout (qwerty, qwertz, azerty...). That is not supported by qt directly.

So either I am looking for a way that was not mentioned in the Qt docs (or hidden somewhere) or, more likely, a way to pre-process the keys in pure python before that by translating the hardware key number to the actual key in the current layout on the program start-up.

I can give the actual key to pyqt then, or any other toolkit, which does not need to know anything then.

The key left of the one-key has the the key number "1" sometimes (see http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.keyboardtechref%2Fdoc%2Fkybdtech%2FKey.htm ).

If I intercept this key in qt and print out its "nativeScanCode" I get "49" as result.

So all in all I would prefer a python only solution, but Qt dependent is also fine.

Reason:
The reason is that this is a very comfortable key to use (regarding the layout) but highly language dependent. In some keyboard-languages it is even a 'dead key' which requires a second key to create a char with diacritic.

If you want to test it yourself just take the z and the y keys with qwerty and qwertz, that is the simpler example than the key left of the one, but in principle it is the same problem.
The goal is a shortcut that is always triggered by the key in the lower left corner of the keyboard, no matter if qwertz or qwerty (as the name suggest, the difference between these two is that z and y are reversed)

Comment: You're experiencing the problem discussed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3872085/344347).

Comment: Sorry, you still don't get it.  This has nothing to do with dead keys.   
Dead keys just add one additional layer of problems, but until the original problem remains we don't even need to think about this. 

The last paragraph in the question recommends that for own tests you can as well use z and y. It is simpler because these are non-dead keys in any layout.

Comment: Why has it nothing to do with dead keys? We were talking about dead keys. You're trying to bind a shortcut to a dead key press event, don't you?

Comment: no. Ok, new task: Bind a shortcut to the key which is in the bottom left of the physical keyboard. in qwerty it is labelled "z" and it qwertz it is labeled "y". So in England you have to press the key labeled "z" to activate and in Germany you have to press the key "y" to activate.

Set your keyboard layout to test it:
setxkbmap -layout de,de

Comment: Now I got it. I've updated my answer. It seems that I've experienced the dead key press event problem, and you were not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement a shortcut independent from keyboard layout, you need to reimplement `keyPressEvent` of your widget and check `keyEvent.nativeScanCode()` value. For example, to track the key that is assigned to 'Z' in QWERTY and to 'Y' in QWERTZ, you can use the following:

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
      def keyPressEvent(self, event):
          if event.nativeScanCode() == 52:
              print "Pressed!"
```

Note that grave accent key is special. In some layouts it's a dead key, that's why in some systems keyPressEvent may not appear until the next key is pressed. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872085/dead-keys-dont-arrive-at-keypressedevent).

QShortCut is based on QKeySequence, and QKeySequence doesn't support native scan codes, so QShortCut can't be used in this task.

Comment: No. Shortcuts depend on the current keyboard layout. Please read the question again. This is about locale independence.

Comment: Did you try to run it? I have tried, and it works fine for me using two different layouts. Also, the "`" character is the default character for this key in QWERTY layout.

Comment: Yes. I can't even run it. On QWERTZ the "`" key is a dead key with a shift modifier to the key left of backspace. So this is not even possible as a regular shortcut.
This is exactly the problem: If your app would use this shortcut it would not even be inconvenient to use it but impossible for complete central and south/east Europe.

In conclusion: using QKeySequence with a char binds the key that produces this char at the moment, in ths current keyboard layout.

Comment: Maybe my question was unclear. I edited the first sentence to clarify.

Comment: OK, I'll try to add this layout and check. And why can't you *run* it?

Comment: It does run. Just the shortcut can't be activated because there is no way to even type this char in one keystroke. You need at least two (Shift and ', followed by space)
Anyway, that is a detail that complicated things further and doesn't really matter here. I could switch the layout to "no dead keys" and then I would be able to type this char with a single keystroke. But it would still be on the key left of Backspace, and not on the key left to the one.